# Silverlight Listbox not binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, listbox

I am trying to bind a Silverlight listbox thru the codebehind on a button click.

Here is the XAML

```
           <ListBox  x:Name="MyList" DataContext="Listdata" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Listdata}">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Codehind of Mainpage.xaml.cs here. I've noticed that if I call the line buildListData(); before I set  MyList.DataContext = Listdata; then it works. Otherwise like I have here below it doesnt. Suppse I have to update the Listbox dynamically on a button click event then I would typically call the buildListData(); method in its event handler. This would not work either as Im updating the value of the **Listdata** property after setting its datacontext. Any help?

```
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private List<ListData> _listData;
        public List<ListData> Listdata
        {
            get {return _listData ;}
        set { _listData = value; FirePropertyChanged("Listdata"); }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }




    public MainPage()
    {       
        // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();

            MyList.DataContext = Listdata;
            MyList.ItemsSource = Listdata;
            buildListData();
            FirePropertyChanged("Listdata");
    }



        private void buildListData ()
        {
            Listdata = new List<ListData>();

            Listdata.Add(new ListData(){Name="Person 1", Age=30});
            Listdata.Add(new ListData() { Name = "Person 2", Age = 31 });
            Listdata.Add(new ListData() { Name = "Person 3", Age = 32 });
            Listdata.Add(new ListData() { Name = "Person 4", Age = 33 });
            Listdata.Add(new ListData() { Name = "Person 5", Age = 34 });

        }
}
```

Here is the ListData class

```
 public class ListData : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    private int _age;


    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; FirePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; FirePropertyChanged("Age"); }
    } 

}
```

ViewMOdelBase class here

```
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }



}
```

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this (I think). You are binding to a list. The list then gets updated, BUT - here's the funny part - the list doesn't understand that adding Items to it means it was updated, so it doesn't technically fire the property changed event. That happens when you make it a new List()

So try this - first, dump the list, use an ObservableCollection. Wait, we aren't done.

Now, add a handler for the CollectionChanged() event, which will fire when you add items to it.

Now in the CollectionChanged event, call FirePropertyChanged(this) from the ListData class.

Now the UI will know the list changed because items were added to it.

Comment: actually yes the propertchanged does fire when I new up the list. However it doesnt when I add elements. SO I guess for the list box the Listdata is still empty. To counter this I called the FirePropertyChanged("Listdata"); method just after calling buildListData(); That didnt work either. Im gonna try the observalbe collection route. Thanks for the hint. Will post back if it worked. --

Comment: ok, so I tried the ObservableCollection<ListData>. It worked, but without implementing CollectionChanged event. Is it required to implement CollectionChanged? Am I missing something important by not doing that? I also noticed one thing. setting the listbox's data context in the xaml doesnt work for me. I have to set it in the xaml.cs file. Any idea how this is so?